# Dataframe groupby column overlaps with dataframe index when calculating std

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

As an illustration I have this data. Even though it worked well when I perform cumsum function  according to Column days as groupby,  as I perform the same state for STD function as regards days list. Unintentionally it makes index numbers groupby

Working code:

```
df['Vol'] = df['Lot2'].groupby(df['days']).cumsum()

      Lot2    days    mid    Vol        VWAPx       std
0     550.0      1  75.35    550.0  75.350000       NaN
1     619.0      1  75.30   1169.0  75.323524  0.075410
2     2227.0     1  75.30   3396.0  75.308098  0.710670
3     1776.0     1  75.30   5172.0  75.305317       NaN
4     1000.0     1  75.35   6172.0  75.312557       NaN
5     6274.0     1  75.40  12446.0  75.356637  0.143375
6     5000.0     1  75.35  17446.0  75.354735  0.190802
7     420.0      1  75.35  17866.0  75.354623  0.225577
8     108.0      1  75.30  17974.0  75.354295  0.374943
9     132.0      1  75.35  18106.0  75.354264  0.122366
```

The problem is with this one (as it returns std above):

```
df['std'] = df['VWAPx'].groupby(df['days']).std()
```

The result of std should be the same for all "days" group the same.

```
df['std'] = df['VWAPx'].groupby(df['days'], as_index=False).std()
```

Returns TypeError: as_index=False only valid with DataFrame

Note: days list consist of numbers between 1-30 (excludes 3-4 for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```
df['std'] = df['VWAPx'].groupby(df['days']).transform('std')
print(df)

     Lot2  days    mid      Vol      VWAPx       std
0   550.0     1  75.35    550.0  75.350000  0.022094
1   619.0     1  75.30   1169.0  75.323524  0.022094
2  2227.0     1  75.30   3396.0  75.308098  0.022094
3  1776.0     1  75.30   5172.0  75.305317  0.022094
4  1000.0     1  75.35   6172.0  75.312557  0.022094
5  6274.0     1  75.40  12446.0  75.356637  0.022094
6  5000.0     1  75.35  17446.0  75.354735  0.022094
7   420.0     1  75.35  17866.0  75.354623  0.022094
8   108.0     1  75.30  17974.0  75.354295  0.022094
9   132.0     1  75.35  18106.0  75.354264  0.022094
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know though, why it wasn't working the same way as cumsum()

Comment: `cumsum` return a series rather than `std` return an unique value. `sum` has the same behavior as `std`